# Creating a Bigram class that can hold two objects like Strings or other Bigrams (Java)

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a class that can hold two objects like Strings or other Bigrams for bigger n-grams but i'm not sure if I did it right. Below is the code for my class. Also, if I did write the class correctly how would I go about initializing it in another class?

```
public class Bigram<E1,E2> {

public E1 first;
public E2 second;

public Bigram(E1 first, E2 second) {

    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
}

public E1 getFirst() {
    return first;
}

public E2 getSecond() {
    return second;
}
```

Comment: `Bigram<String,Integer> b = new Bigram<>("hello",1);` using constructor